# MVC5 Outputcache is not working as per documentation

Tags: model-view-controller, outputcache

In my MVC application the server located(Location= "Server") Outputcache it is not working as expected. Does it works perfectly for browsers but not for a webrequest. I want to generate cache from a webrequest call. It is not recognized by browsers? Any easy idea to see the outputcache keys? IIs tools or something?